# React router dom - Form onSubmit pass input value to another component as well as redirect to that component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Here's my app component that renders an input for user to type in. What I want to achieve is that whatever input that the user writes in will be passed down to the `Films` component. That text is then will be used as a query param to get data from an api endpoint

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Films from "../Films";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    const onSubmit = (event) => {
       setRedirect(true);
    };
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <p className="films-analysis-service">Films Analysis Service </p>
        <form id="input-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            id="input-box" 
            value={text} 
            onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button className="button" type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
        {redirect && (
          <Route
            exact
            path="/films"
            render={(props) => <Films text={text} />}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is my Films component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./style.css";

const axios = require("axios");
    
const Films = ({ text }) => {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const fetchMoviesByDirectorName = () => {
    let config = {
      headers: { Authorization: apiKey },
      params: {
        directorName: text, //the text that is passed down from App component
      },
    };

    axios.get(filmsEndpointURL, config);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMoviesByDirectorName();
  }, [movies]);

  return (
    ...

  );

};
export default Films;
```

At the moment I'm just trying to print out the data that I would get back but unfortunately I don't think my input value is passed down properly. I don't think my usage of `Route` is correct.. and it's not redirecting to `/films` component. What changes should I do to my App.js?

Comment: I guess you could use `onChange` on the `input` and capture there the `event.target.value` instead in `onSubmit` event of the form. Good debugging option is to add a `console.log(event.target.value)` line into `onSubmit` and you will see the value will be not the one what you are looking for - most probably.

Comment: I've edited my post with changes on onSubmit and setText for the input onChange. I guess my problem is that it's not redirecting to Films component with the text as its prop

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to do `event.preventDefault()` in `onSubmit`

```js
const onSubmit = (event) => {
       event.preventDefault(); //<----- like this
       setRedirect(true);
    };
```

2. You can use [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) to navigate to `Films` not `Route`.

Refactored code (using Redirect)

```js
<Router>
  <div>
    <p className="films-analysis-service">Films Analysis Service </p>
    <form id="input-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input-box"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button className="button" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
    <Route exact path="/films" render={(props) => <Films text={text} {...props}/>} /> //<----see here
    {redirect && <Redirect to="/films" />} //<----see here
  </div>
  <Route></Route>
</Router>;
```

3. You can also use [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object to navigate to `Films`

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    //  setRedirect(true);//<----no need
    customHistory.push("/films");
  };
  return (
    <Router history={customHistory}>
      <div>
        <p className="films-analysis-service">Films Analysis Service </p>
        <form id="input-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="input-box"
            value={text}
            onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button className="button" type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
        <Route exact path="/films" render={(props) => <Films text={text} />} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Okay, I missed that line of code by mistake but this doesn't really solve the issue I'm having

Comment: yes, i got your issue... editing my answer.. 2 mins